# Where to place register function for ViewControl in Platypi

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have been going through [Platypi.io/docs/getting-started/][1] but have gotten stuck at the section about adding functions to allow users to register for the demo app (https://platypi.io/docs/getting-started/allow-users-to-register)

The specific step is

> Now, let's add our register function. This function will be fired whenever the plat-button is tapped or clicked. In the template, we defined our button's tap event by specifying a function in the plat-tap attribute. The function name is register, so when that button is clicked, the register function will be fired on our ViewControl. Add the register function to the view control (in public/viewcontrols/register/register.viewcontrol.ts:

```
register() {
    this.context.error = '';
    this.userRepository.register(this.context.email,
        this.context.password,
        this.context.firstname,
        this.context.lastname)
    .then((success) => {
        this.navigator.navigate(HomeViewControl);
    }).catch((error) => {
        this.context.error = error;
    });
}
```

Where do I add this function? If I put it in the RegisterViewControl (like [this][2]) class I get this error: `error TS2094: The property 'navigator' does not exist on value of type 'RegisterViewControl'.    this.navigator.navigate(HomeViewControl);` Outside the class, the syntax doesn't work.

I know my way around Javascript, but am new to TypeScript. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RegisterViewControl` should be extending the `BaseViewControl`, and at some level it should be extending `plat.ui.ViewControl`. `plat.ui.ViewControl` has a property called `navigator` on it. From your error, it looks like there might be something wrong with how the `RegisterViewControl` is defined.

If the above solution doesn't work, could you provide the code for the entire RegisterViewControl file?

EDIT: It definitely looks like you have it correct. There is a possibility that something is wrong with the declaration `.d.ts` files. Try deleting the `.tscache` folder and then running `npm install` again. It might give you more useful errors.

We recently (as in yesterday) updated the framework and UI projects to deploy a different structure. It is possible that in your `public/typings/tsd.d.ts` you have the following references:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/platypus/platypus.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/platypusui/platypusui.d.ts" />
```

Double check the node_modules directories, it is possible you need to change the `tsd.d.ts` to the following:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/platypus/dist/platypus.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/platypusui/dist/platypusui.d.ts" />
```

If this is the case, you should also go into the `public/common/css/main.less` file and change this line:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/platypusui/platypus";
```

to this:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/platypusui/dist/platypus";
```

Comment: Looks like my link to the gist for that file got lost: here is the whole file https://gist.github.com/irowebbn/c3b1fc5387a0928588d9

Comment: I implemented your changes and now `grunt` runs without errors, but localhost:3000 still only shows "Hello World" Should I be seeing other changes on the output?

Comment: Okay. Got everything to work for register and login, but in the home.viewcontrol.ts I keep getting the error that `cannot find external module ../order/order.viewcontrol` which I imported the top of the file

Comment: Make sure that you have a viewcontrol at `../order/order.viewcontrol`, and that you are exporting the ViewControl using the `export = OrderViewControl` construct.